# how to decrease decimal places in gridview column asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to show only 2 decimal places in gridview column. column name is InsuaranceAmount,TotalAmount and TravelAssistAmoun.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookingDetailsEmailRS.Length - 1; i++)
 {
BookingDetailsEmailRS[] bookingDetailsEmailRS = b.GetBookingDetails(soap, emailid, out    errorCode, out  errorAtNode);
 GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS.Select(obj => new
        {
            TravelerName = obj.Travelers[0].FirstName + obj.Travelers[0].MiddleName + obj.Travelers[0].LastName,
            obj.BookingNumber,
            obj.BookingStatus,
            obj.ContactNumber,
            obj.CouponDiscountAmount,
            obj.DepartureDate,
            obj.FromCity,
            obj.ToCity,
            obj.PaidAmount,
            obj.TicketType,
            obj.InsuaranceAmount,
            obj.TotalAmount,
            obj.TravelAssistAmount
        }).ToList();


        GridView1.DataBind();    
 }
```

In this variable bookingDetailsEmailRS, I got the response.

Comment: How are you binding data into your gridview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use DataFormat property :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="InsuaranceAmount" HeaderText="Total Data"  
     ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="totaldata" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" />
```

For the second part of your question use Eval method's second parameter to format your data :

```
<%# Eval("InsuaranceAmount", "{0:0.00}") %>
```

[This might also be helpful](http://blog.weareon.net/c-dataformatstrings/)

Comment: I tried these syntax  <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalAmount" HeaderText="Total Data"  
               ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="totaldata" DataFormatString="{0:n2}" />
        </Columns> in the <asp:GridView> tag.

Comment: try instead of DataFormatString="{0:n2}" try: DataFormatString="{0:0.00}"

Comment: It's work but It create new column. I am not want create new column. I want this action apply on these particular column.

Comment: can you add the grid view to your question?

Comment: In .aspx page I added these code <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalAmount" HeaderText="TotalAmount"  
               ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" />
        </Columns> and .cs page I shown in my que.

Comment: If it worked for you, please consider mark it as the right answer so others will also find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

The `Eval` function has two parameters, the first is the `Bind`able field and the second is a format for the field.  Use something like `{0:0.00}` in this portion of the control's fields definition.

Answer (score 1):

In case of bound columns, you have a `DataFormatString` attribute. You could do something like to show only 2 decimal places in gridview column:

`DataFormatString="{0:0.00}"`

Ex:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TotalAmount" HeaderText="Total Amount" DataFormatString="{0:0.00}" />
```

Reference: [Numeric Custom Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: It's work but I want to edit these particular column not create the new column.

Comment: Then you need to use the `asp:TemplateField` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx